# Angular problem with navigation menu when minimized

Tags: angular, navbar, bootstrap-5

Angular since when the page is minimized (for example on a cell phone), when I select a link from the minimized menu I get a 404 error as if the page did not exist, if the menu is complete there is no problem since it navigates to any menu option without problems.

I've tried everything, I've been having this problem for 2 weeks now, I even tried Angular Universal but my site contains data that is not static.

```
<div class="navbar-area-two">
  <div class="exto-responsive-nav">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="exto-responsive-menu">
        <div class="logo">
          <a routerLink="/">
            <img
              src="assets/img/logo/logoIntteinoloB.png"
              alt="Intteinolo Proximity Solutions, LLC"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="exto-nav" *transloco="let t">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">
          <img
            src="assets/img/logo/logoIntteinoloB.png"
            alt="Intteinolo Proximity Solutions, LLC"
          />
        </a>

        <!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
        <!--
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        -->

        <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse mean-menu"
          id="navbarSupportedContent"
          [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"
        >
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                routerLink="/"
                class="nav-link"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
                aria-current="page"
                >{{ t("NavBar.home") }}</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                routerLink="/about"
                class="nav-link"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
                >{{ t("NavBar.about") }}</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:51029/"
                    >Home Intteinolo</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="others-options seo-option">
            <div class="language-list">
              <div class="select-box">
                <div class="nice-select" software-tabindex="0">
                  <span class="current"> English </span>
                  <ul class="list">
                    <li
                      data-value="en"
                      class="option selected"
                      (click)="changeSiteLanguage('en')"
                    >
                      English
                    </li>
                    <li
                      data-value="es"
                      class="option"
                      (click)="changeSiteLanguage('es')"
                    >
                      Español
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--
            <div class="seo-cart-icon">
              <a routerLink="/cart" (click)="changeLanguage($event)">
                <i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i>
                <span class="point">3</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            -->

            <div class="option-item">
              <i class="search-btn fas fa-search"></i>
              <i class="close-btn fa fa-times"></i>
              <div class="search-overlay search-popup">
                <div class="search-box">
                  <form class="search-form">
                    <input
                      class="search-input"
                      name="search"
                      placeholder="{{ t('Common.search') }}"
                      type="text"
                    />
                    <button class="search-button" type="submit">
                      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              class="sidebar-menu-icon"
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target="#myModal2"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/shape/shape17.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--
          <div
          class="collapse navbar-collapse mean-menu"
          id="navbarSupportedContent"
          [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed"
        >
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                routerLink="/"
                class="nav-link"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
                aria-current="page"
                >{{ t("NavBar.home") }}</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a
                href="/about"
                routerLink="/about"
                class="nav-link"
                routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
                >{{ t("NavBar.about") }}</a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a
                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                href="#"
                role="button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:51029/"
                    >Home Intteinolo</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="others-options seo-option">
            <div class="language-list">
              <div class="select-box">
                <div class="nice-select" software-tabindex="0">
                  <span class="current"> English </span>
                  <ul class="list">
                    <li
                      data-value="en"
                      class="option selected"
                      (click)="changeSiteLanguage('en')"
                    >
                      English
                    </li>
                    <li
                      data-value="es"
                      class="option"
                      (click)="changeSiteLanguage('es')"
                    >
                      Español
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="option-item">
              <i class="search-btn fas fa-search"></i>
              <i class="close-btn fa fa-times"></i>
              <div class="search-overlay search-popup">
                <div class="search-box">
                  <form class="search-form">
                    <input
                      class="search-input"
                      name="search"
                      placeholder="{{ t('Common.search') }}"
                      type="text"
                    />
                    <button class="search-button" type="submit">
                      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              class="sidebar-menu-icon"
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target="#myModal2"
            >
              <img src="assets/img/shape/shape17.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap)

Comment: Remember that in angular you **not** use `<a href=..>` else `<a routerLink="...>`. NOTE: It's impossible help you without see the related code about your problem.

Comment: Here is my URL http://intteinolo.net/ Could you help me if I add you to my github repository?